BroadcastReceiver does not work on android 14 in Widget
Configured a widget to track WiFi status and display it in the Widget
On Android 14, when you turn off or turn on WiFi in the widget, the status changes only if you decrease or increase the Widget and you can immediately see that all the changes were queued and executed.
On Android 12 everything works fine.
kotlin

class WifiStateReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION == intent.action) {
            val wifiState = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN)
            val isWifiEnabled = wifiState == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED
            updateWidget(context, isWifiEnabled)
        }
    }

    private fun updateWidget(context: Context, isWifiEnabled: Boolean) {
        val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
        val componentName = ComponentName(context, MyAppWidgetProvider::class.java)
        val appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(componentName)

        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_layout)
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.statusWifi, if (isWifiEnabled) "Включено" else "Выключено")
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
        }
    }
}

kotlin
class MyAppWidgetProvider : AppWidgetProvider() {
    private var wifiStateReceiver: WifiStateReceiver? = null

    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray,
    ) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds)
    }

    override fun onEnabled(context: Context) {
        super.onEnabled(context)
        Log.d("WifiStateReceiver", "onEnabled")
        if (wifiStateReceiver == null) {
            wifiStateReceiver = WifiStateReceiver()
            val filter = IntentFilter(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                context.applicationContext.registerReceiver(wifiStateReceiver, filter, Context.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED )
            }

        }
    }
    override fun onDisabled(context: Context) {
        super.onDisabled(context)
        Log.d("WifiStateReceiver", "onDisabled")
        wifiStateReceiver?.let {
            context.applicationContext.unregisterReceiver(it)
            wifiStateReceiver = null
        }
    }
}


kotlin

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:installLocation="internalOnly">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Widget2"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".MyAppWidgetProvider"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".WifiStateReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".WifiStatusService" />
        
    </application>



</manifest>

kotlin

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen">
</appwidget-provider>


What does "only if you decrease or increase the Widget" mean?

The widget can be resized directly on the device screen where it is located.
